# New gem with Bundler, from a class

Tags: ruby, bundler

When we run the `bundle gem new_gem` command, a directory is created with those files:

```
  create  new_gem/Gemfile
  create  new_gem/Rakefile
  create  new_gem/.gitignore
  create  new_gem/new_gem.gemspec
  create  new_gem/lib/new_gem.rb
  create  new_gem/lib/new_gem/version.rb
```

By default, the file `new_gem/lib/new_gem.rb` is a module named `NewGem`.

My question is the following: how can I do if `NewGem` is a class?  Rather then having `NewGem::NewGem`, I would like to just define this class (without a root module).

I tried to just replace module by class inside this file, and then make a local gem in order to test it, but after its installation, I can not load it in IRB (with `require 'new_gem'`).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ask yourself why you want to do this.  The module is there to [namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) your gem's code.  Typically to provide a context for all the classes within, but even in a single class gem, this would help to provide conflicts with other code out in the world.

Unless your class is named `SomethingThatCouldNeverPossiblyBeDefinedAnywhereElse`, leaving that module in place is probably a good thing.  And regardless of that, leaving the module intact is still a good thing as it's the convention, and what people expect when examining/using your code.

With that in mind, there are a few things you'd need to do if you wanted a single class gem.

1. The generated gemspec wants to `require 'new_gem/version'` to find it's version number.  Change that to simply `require 'new_gem'`.
2. The gemspec also lists its contained files using `git ls`, and the generated gem package already has `new_gem/version` included in the pre-built git repo.  Remove this:

   ```
   git rm lib/new_gem/version.rb
   ```
3. Change your `new_gem` module to a class, as you did previously.
4. Remove the generated `version.rb` require from your class, and instead define the version there, e.g.:

   ```
   class NewGem
     VERSION = '0.0.1'
   end
   ```
5. Finally install the gem via `rake install`.  You won't be able to load it in IRB until you've done this.

Comment: The problem is still there. I think the only clean way is to put the class in a main module, as you explained it. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it *should* work.  I did actually go through these steps myself when I answered it, and I was able to load the class-only gem into IRB without issue.  But yeah, just sticking with the module namespace is probably the best route.